# iTunes link not working

Tags: itunes, ios-appstore, url

So there's that app I found from my PC and should like to download:
http://www.itunes.apple.com/jp/app/id666206963

When I click the link, my device asks me if I want to open it in the app store, which I confirm.
The store opens but where the app is supposed to be displayed, a white rectangle is shown that stays a white rectangle, no matter how long I wait.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

That link you have is not correct.

Use this link for your app

https://itunes.apple.com/jp/app/net-ma-que-mjmobairu/id666206963?mt=8

[image: web site]

or from the source: http://sega-mj.com/

Comment: Right, "httpS" and no "www", thank you.
However, that does not solve the issue, I'm still getting a white rectangle, even with your link.

Comment: see my update, and your iTunes store should ask you to switch to japan, since that app is not available in the USA.